# springboot war working with embedded tomcat but not with external tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, tomcat9

I have been working on a springboot 2.3.4 application with spring security. It's working with embedded tomcat. We want to make it work with external application servers like tomcat and jboss. I have tried to deploy the war file in external tomcat server. when hitting the endpoints I receive 404 error code. Here is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.teradata</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelstudio</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>modelstudio</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>ModelStudio Application</description>

    <properties>
       <java.version>13</java.version>
       <start-class>
            com.teradata.modelstudio.ModelStudioApplication
       </start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.teradata.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>terajdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <finalName>modelstudio</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>static/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>ModelStudioUI/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>static/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

My JWT Entry point is:

```
package com.teradata.modelstudio.filter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.teradata.modelstudio.service.CustomAuthenticationProviderService;
import com.teradata.modelstudio.utils.JwtUtil;
import com.teradata.modelstudio.utils.Logger;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Component
public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProviderService service;
    
    @Autowired JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
        Logger.info("==================="+requestURI);
        Pattern mega = Pattern.compile(
                "\\/*.css|\\/*.js|\\/*.png|\\/*.jpg|\\/assets\\/*.*|\\/*.woff2|\\/*.woff|\\/*.ttf|\\/swagger-resources\\/*|/servicemanagement/configuration/*|/servicemanagement/etlframework/*|/servicemanagement/refreshCache/*");

        // System.out.println(requestURI);

        if (httpServletRequest.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")// || requestURI.equalsIgnoreCase("/index.html")
                || requestURI.equalsIgnoreCase("/favicon.ico") || mega.matcher(requestURI).find() || requestURI.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            return;
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
//      System.out.println("+++URL in jwt request filter:"+url);
        if (url.contains("auth") || url.contains("dbcontent") || url.contains("favico")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
            return;
        }

        String requestTokenHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String password = null;
        String serverUrl = null;
        String dbName = null;
        String authType = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtUtil.getUsernameFromJWT(jwtToken);
                password = jwtUtil.getPasswordFromJWT(jwtToken);
                serverUrl = jwtUtil.getServerUrlFromJWT(jwtToken);
                dbName = jwtUtil.getDbNameFromJWT(jwtToken);
                authType = jwtUtil.getAuthTypeFromJWT(jwtToken);
                jwtUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, username);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }

        } else {
            throw new IOException("Invalid Authorization");
        }
        
        
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, username)) {
                
                CustomUserPrincipal customUserPrincipal = new CustomUserPrincipal(username, password, serverUrl, dbName, authType);

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(customUserPrincipal, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

My Security config file:

```
package com.teradata.modelstudio.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.teradata.modelstudio.filter.JwtFilter;
import com.teradata.modelstudio.payload.JwtAuthenticationResponse;
import com.teradata.modelstudio.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.teradata.modelstudio.service.CustomAuthenticationProviderService;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProviderService authenticationProviderService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    
    @Autowired
    JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    
    @Autowired
    private com.teradata.modelstudio.filter.SimpleCORSFilter simpleCORSFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(
                HttpMethod.GET,
              "/",
              "/*.html",
              "/*.svg",
              "/*.png",
              "/*.woff",
              "/*.woff2",
              "/*.svg",
              "/*.jpg",
              "/*.json",
              "/favicon.ico",
              "/**/*.html",
              "/**/*.css",
              "/**/*.js",
              "/**/*.svg",
              "/**/*.png",
              "/**/*.jpg",
              "/**/*.ico",
              "/**/*.icons",
              "/resources/**",
              "/assets/",
              "/static/**",
              "/h2-console/**"
        ).permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/dbcontent/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(simpleCORSFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProviderService);
    }
    
    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

One of my controller classes are:

```
package com.teradata.modelstudio.controllers;

import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.teradata.modelstudio.exception.ModelStudioException;
import com.teradata.modelstudio.utils.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("dbcontent")
public class DBContentController {
    
    @GetMapping(path="servers", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getServers() {
        try {
            String dbConFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"db-con";
            File file = new File(dbConFilePath);
            String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8");
            // Convert JSON string to JSONObject
            JSONObject fileContents = new JSONObject(content);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(fileContents.toString());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Logger.error("Unable to get servers: "+e.getMessage());
            throw new ModelStudioException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is my main class

```
package com.teradata.modelstudio;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication(
          exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
             HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
             DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
             })
public class ModelstudioApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ModelstudioApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ModelstudioApplication.class);
    }

}
```

With embedded tomcat serever, I hit:

*localhost:8080/dbcontent/servers*

and I get the results while on external I do the following:

*localhost:8080/modelstudio/dbcontent/servers*

and I get 404.

Can anyone please help and advise me how to resolve this issue with external server like tomcat.

Comment: Your `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency is scoped provided. Which means it isn't available when deploying on tomcat, basically you are losing the whole web part. What you probably wanted to do is add the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency as well and mark that provided (as to not include the tomcat dependencies). So add that and remove the scope from `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Comment: I have already this dependency and marked this as provided. I did some search on it and I found 2 things that possibly are causing the problems.

Comment: 1-  When we run with embeded tomcat in springboot, then by default it knows from where to server static contents. In this case static content is in src/main/resource/static folder. So if we do localhost:8080 then it means that requestURI is "/" and it needs to serve index.html. In case of external tomcat, it doesn't know from where to serve this static content. So in case of external, path is localhost:8080/modelstudio and requestURI becomes /modelstudio/ and it doesn't find any handler and returns 404.

Comment: As I stated the problem is that your spring-boot-starter-web has the scope provided. Remove that scope, without spring web, the application simply doesn’t start because there are no web classes. It works with the embedded one because it adds those provided dependencies as well due to the special class loader.

Comment: 2 - Other problem is that when we use embeded tomcat, then paths don't include server context path. In case of external tomcat, all request land with context path. so in embeded, uri was "/auth/login" but in external it would become "/modelstudio/auth/login". So security filter doesn't let it go and will ask for authorization and hence 403 forbidden error. So how can we accomodate these context paths. Do we need to include in all endpoint paths?

Comment: Thanks Deinum. I am able to resolve the issue with the changes you have recommended and some changes in security filter. I also added a server.servlet.context-path property to make it consistent with embeded and external tomcat. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Am new to the java/ tomcat environment. Could any one of you guys please explain in details as what needs to be done. Been stuck with this issue for long time now